# Using source command for other users logged in

Tags: bash, command

My problem is about using the source command for everyone logged in.

Let's say I have a file with the content:

```
#!/bin/bash
alias ha='echo test'
```

Now if I source it and write `ha`, I'd get the message `test`.

Now what if there's someone else logged in, and I want it to be sourced for his account? Can you write something like `source (username) (filename)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that other uses have read permission to your script, and read permissions to its directory and parent directories, they can source that file.   Assuming your user name is "thesourcequestion", and you are keeping the alias file (let's call it alias ) in your home directory, other users can source it with the following command:

```
source ~thesourcequestion/alias
```

Or just (same thing):

```
. ~thesourcequestion/alias
```

Incidentally, some shells only accept the `source` keyword (like c-shell IIRC).

If you are the admin of the box, consider the solution presented here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/610052/how-can-i-preset-aliases-for-all-users/986053

In short, there are system files that can be modified that will create the alias for users.  The alias will be available to them next time they login.

Don't overlook the part of my answer about providing permissions to your file.  For example, you can give read permissions to the file this way:

```
chmod a+r ~thesourcequestion/alias
```

The above syntax adds (+) the read attribute (r) to all (a).